# How do I combine vectors into a dataframe using an index vector in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, indexing, bind

I have a dataframe `df` of answers to a survey (IPAQ) with 27 questions. These are the first 8 columns:

```
df
       ID   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    28     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2    52     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3    97     1     0     0     1    60     0     0
 4   100     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 5   112     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 6   157     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 7   252     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 8   254     1     0     0     4   120     7   180
 9   309     1     0     0     2    30     0     0
10   332     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I have created variables which convert these answers into meaningful totals e.g.:

```
###Housework and gardening###
gard.vig = (5.5 * df$`14` * df$`15`)
gard.mod = (4.0 * df$`16` * df$`17`)
house.mod = (3.0 * df$`18` * df$`19`)
total.hg = (gard.mod + gard.vig + house.mod)

###Leisure###
lei.walk = (3.3 * df$`20` * df$`21`)
lei.mod = (4.0 * df$`24` * df$`25`)
lei.vig = (8.0 * df$`22` * df$`23`)
tot.lei = (lei.walk + lei.mod + lei.vig)
```

I want to combine/ bind these variables together in a dataframe/tibble using the `ID` variable from the original `df`
to create something like this:

```
ID lei.walk lei.mod lei.vig total.lei gard.mod gard.vig etc.
28 600      55      89      etc.
52 etc. 
etc.
```

Comment: Your calculation doesn't seem to be per `ID` do you just want to `cbind` them? `cbind(df[1], gard.vig, gard.mod, house.mod, total.hg......)` ?

Comment: Yes I could do that! But does that guarantee that the variable answers much up with the correct ID. Do I need to create a for loop instead?

Comment: Order does not change when you multiply vectors. See `1:10 * 2` Also it looks like all `ID`s are unique in itself and do not repeat.

Comment: Thanks. that was an easy solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the vector are already calculated we can directly `cbind` them

```
cbind(df[1], gard.vig, gard.mod, house.mod, total.hg, lei.walk, 
             lei.mod, lei.vig, tot.lei)
```

Or using `data.frame`

```
data.frame(ID = df$ID, gard.vig, gard.mod, house.mod, total.hg,
                lei.walk,lei.mod, lei.vig, tot.lei)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
tibble(df[1],  gard.vig, gard.mod, house.mod, total.hg, lei.walk, 
         lei.mod, lei.vig, tot.lei)
```